# Merge sort output issue

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to code merge sort through recursion. However I'm not getting the output in proper sorted order. Please correct my code and tell me the detail about my error.
The program takes the number of elements and elements from the user. Based on the data, the program shoud give the elements in sorted order.
The code is as follow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#define max 20

using namespace std;

int data[max];
int nw[max];
void mergeparts(int, int, int);


void merge_sort(int low, int high){
    int mid;

    if(low<high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        merge_sort(low, mid);
        merge_sort(mid+1, high);
        mergeparts(low, mid, high);
    }
}

void mergeparts(int low, int mid, int high){

    for(int i=low; i<high; i++){
        nw[i] = data[i];
    }
    int i = low;
    int j = mid+1;
    int k = low;


    while((i <= mid)&&(j <= high)){
        if(nw[i]<=nw[j]){
            data[k]=nw[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            data[k]=nw[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while(i <= mid){
        data[k] = nw[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

    while(j <= high){
        data[k] = nw[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for(int i=low; i<high; i++){
        data[i] = nw[i];
    }

}

int main(){
    int n;

    cout<<"Enter the number of elements"<<endl;
    cin>>n;



    cout<<"Enter the "<<n<<" numbers."<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>data[i];
    }

    cout<<"The unsorted list is: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\t",data[i]);
    }
    cout<<endl;

    merge_sort(0,n+1);

    cout<<"The sorted list is: "<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            printf("%d\t",data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lot of drive-by downvoters this morning, don't take it personally. But this is quite a lot of code to read through, no description of what it does, no comments. Also, you should at least have some sample input/output with your expected output.

Comment: You should try a bit harder ( I learned it the hard way here).
Take a look at this : http://geeksquiz.com/merge-sort/. This is a C solution but it will work in C++ too.
Also, why mix printf and cout?

Comment: @Transcendental: My code is exactly like the link that you have mentioned, only thing is that the input data is static over there and I want it to be dynamic. I wanted to check whether printf and cout works simultaneously in cpp program or not

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not the same as the one from [this](http://geeksquiz.com/merge-sort/) article, as you wrote in your comment. The key difference is in the merging function.

If you carefully examine your code, you will notice that  there are parts of your code that might alter the data array, without saving it's current state; for example:

```
 while(i <= mid){
        data[k] = nw[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
```

Try it out on an array with some 4 elements, e.g. 5,6,4,2 and you will notice some of the original array members will not appear in the output array.

You didn't provide the information about your developing environment, but most of them have debuggers built in. Play around with debugger and you will eventually solve your problem. Or re-read the article and code the algorithm again.

Best of luck.

(Also, in the future, try to be a bit more specific with question title and try to provide some additional information about the problem, like some examples. People here want to help, but not everyone has enough time to read the question, compile, or debug your code. If you're more specific, someone might know the answer just by reading your question, and with no further investigation )